# JQuery detect a NEXT LINE, then append

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

as what my title above, getting the value
 of TEXTAREA, then how to detect if the end is NEXTLINE?

example: I add something a value of my textarea
VALUE:

```
2
32
3
2
3
```

in MySQL it also looks like that

however, in my website it looks like this
VALUE:

```
2 32 3 2 3
```

How can i detect it using Jquery?and making it a NEXT LINE instead of space...

I will appreciate any reply guys...thank you...

Comment: THE ABOVE VALUE with 2 32 3 2 3 without CODE, it must be a VERTICAL ALIGNED numbers...

Comment: did you try the php fucntion `nl2br($text)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so for all clearens for the next person how reads this problem:

to replace the `\n` chars to a readble format you could can use

```
echo nl2br($text);
```